# Is it possible to get an instant notification with PeriodicTask?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, notifications, periodic-task

I'm implementing a `Periodic Task` in WP7 app. As you know, `PeriodicTask` runs for 25 seconds in every `~30 minutes`. But in my app, I should get notifications `instantly`, like when user receive a message. Whatsapp-like apps can do this perfectly but, I searched for google and found nothing. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive notifications "instantly" then you'll need to have the server send the [push] notification.

There is no way that a process that only run (approx.) every 30 minutes can do this.